# set a JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: android-studio, java-home

I installed android studio 2.0 but when I open it, a message is shown indicating that the JAVA_HOME variable needs to be added to environment variables but I am sure that I do it[image]

[image]

Comment: you installed a 32 bit java. install again a x64 bit bro :).

check here the 64bit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: check for this
*** Windows x64 193.68 MB   jdk-8u101-windows-x64.exe ***
and then look for it in "Program Files" only not "Program files (x86)" because x86 means a 32bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jdk path is in C:\Program Files (x86). So I think you installed 32-bit jdk version. 64-bit jdk version should be installed to C:\Program Files

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Java and remove JDK_HOME in environmental paths. Then install 64bit JAVA and Add JDK_HOME again.
(If You Install 64bit AndroidStudio on your machine, Install java 64 bit only.)